# React doesn't take well the td colSpan attrib

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I'm trying to use a `<table>...</table>` inside React. I have this:

```
 <table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colSpan={2}> ... </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

React ignores `colSpan`. I've been dealing with this for a while. I found some question like this here in Stackoverflow, and the answers are to camelcase the colspan, but it doesn't work for me. It goes the same in `<th colSpan={2}>...</th>` What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code is fine - [pen](https://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/jaVabb)

Comment: the solution is to use `colSplan='2'`, not `{2}`... thanks to @VivekDoshi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
<td colSpan='2'>
```

Not

```
<td colSpan={2}>
```

Comment: that is a hit!!! this solves the problem! thanks!

Comment: @assembler, will you please accept and upvote the answer?

Comment: I can not perform votes till tomorrow. I'll do that then, and thanks again.

Comment: @assembler, Sure thanks man.

Comment: This isn't working for me